# jQuery UI Autocomplete: Pass in string return array

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, kineticjs

I am pretty new to jQuery ui and its autocomplete feature. Is it possible to pass in a simple string (like `var typedText=""`) into jQuery's autocomplete feature and return an array of possible autocomplete matches? I am trying to create a search bar for a KineticJS gui without overlaying a html text input like all the examples. So really I just need to pass in a string and return a list of possible completions.

Here is a snippet of code illustrating my problem.

```
// used as a temp
var typedText="";     //    *** this is what I want to pass into autocomplete***

// Prevent the backspace key from navigating back
$(document).unbind('keydown').bind('keydown', function (event) {

  var doPrevent = false;
  if ((event.keyCode === 8 || event.keyCode === 48 )) { 

      event.preventDefault();

      if(typedText.length>0){
          typedText=typedText.slice(0,-1);
          searchText.setText(typedText);
          textBoxGroup.drawScene();
      }
  }
});

// handle normal "printable" keys
$(document).on('keypress',(function(e){

  if(isMouseOverTestList == false){
    return;
  }
  // get the key
  key=e.which;

  // let keydown handle control keys 
  if(key<32){return;}

  // add the typed character
  typedText+=String.fromCharCode(e.charCode);
  searchText.setText(typedText);;
  textBoxGroup.drawScene();

}));



$(function () {
    var availableTags = [
        "ActionScript",
        "AppleScript",
        "Asp",
        "Scala",
        "Scheme"];
    $(".language").autocomplete({ //--- how do I replace .language with a standard string var?
        source: availableTags,
        focus: function(evt, ui){
            var txtbx = $(this).parent().prev().text();
            $('#result').html(txtbx + ' textbox last focused');
            // ************************ now populate array with data?
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: It sounds like your question is about jQuery selectors, not autocomplete specifically. If that's the case, you can use a JavaScript string variable as a parameter to the jQuery function to be used as a selector.

Comment: thanks... yes that it part of the question. Another is if it is possible to return an array.